# spring+hibernate why is many-to-many relationship not persisted?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have an entity `E1` defined as

```
@Entity
public class E1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name="e1_e2",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e2_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e1_id")
    )
    public Set<E2> e2s = new HashSet<>();
}
```

an entity E2 defined as

```
@Entity
public class E2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "e2s")
    public Set<E1> e1s = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and controller defined as

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class C1 {
    private final E1Repository e1Repository;
    private final E2Repository e2Repository;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public C1(E1Repository e1Repository, E2Repository e2Repository) {
        this.e1Repository = e1Repository;
        this.e2Repository = e2Repository;
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public void c(){
        E1 e1 = new E1();
        E2 e2 = new E2();

        e1Repository.save(e1);
        e2Repository.save(e2);

        em.refresh(e1);
        em.refresh(e2);

        e1.e2s.add(e2);
        e2.e1s.add(e1);

        e1Repository.save(e1);
        e2Repository.save(e2);

        em.refresh(e1);
        em.refresh(e2);
    }

}
```

(`E1Repository` and `E2Repository` are `@Repository` annotated interfaces that extend `JpaRepository` and have empty bodies).

when I step through the `c` method in my debugger, I see that after the last two `em.refresh` lines, both `e1` and `e2` have their sets cleared.

based on other questions I found on Stack Overflow, I tried defining E2 as

```
@Entity
public class E2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name="e1_e2",
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e2_id"),
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e1_id")
    )
    public Set<E1> e1s = new HashSet<>();
}
```

but this did not help.

**Original question** (from before I tried testing the simplified case above)
I have a class `Robot` defined similar to the following:

```
@Entity
class Robot{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="robots")
    private Set<Match> matches = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and a class `Match` similar to

```
@Entity
class Robot{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.Persist,CascadeType.Merge})
    @JoinTable(
        name = "match_robot",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Match_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Robot_id")}
)
private Set<Robot> robots = new HashSet<>();
```

and a class `Result` defined similar to

```
@Entity
public class Result {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Match match;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull(groups = {Default.class, Creating.class})
    private Robot robot;
}
```

and attempt to save the relationship as follows:

```
resultRepository.save(result);
match.getRobots().add(result.getRobot());
result.getRobot().getMatches().add(match);
robotRepository.save(result.getRobot());
matchRepository.save(match);
entityManager.refresh(result);
entityManager.refresh(result.getRobot());
entityManager.refresh(match);
```

where `*Repository` are beans created by spring that implement JpaRepository.
When this code is ran, an insert statement is ran by hibernate for the `result` object (hibernate outputs all of its sql commands to the console), but none for the "match_robot" table. I should not that, before this snippet, `result` is in the transient state of the hibernate entity lifecycle, `match` is in the persisted state, `robot` is in the persisted state, and `result`'s `match` and `robot` properties have been set to `match` and `robot` respectively.

Based on other questions on Stack Overflow and other sites, I have also tried defining the matches variable as

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(
        name = "match_robot",
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Match_id")},
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Robot_id")}
)
private Set<Match> matches = new HashSet<>();
```

which did not help. Other than that, the only recommendation I was seeing was to make sure both entities in the many-to-many relationship were consistant with each other before persisting, but, as far as I can tell, I am doing so here.

How can I persist this relationship?

Edit: the full method for context:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/{match:[0-9]+}/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResultResource createResult(@PathVariable Match match,
                                   @Validated(Result.Creating.class)
                                   @RequestBody Result result) {
    if (match == null) throw new ResourceNotFoundException();

    result.setScorecard(scorecardRepository
            .findById(result.getScorecard().getId()));
    if (result.getScorecard() == null) {
        throw new ScorecardDoesNotExistException();
    }

    result.setMatch(match);

    //remove null scores
    result.getScores().removeIf(
            fieldResult -> fieldResult.getScore() == null
    );

    //replace transient robot with entity from database
    Robot existingRobot = robotRepository
            .findByNumberAndGame(result.getRobot().getNumber(),result.getRobot().getGame());
     if (existingRobot == null) { //create new robot
        //find team for this robot
        Team existingTeam = teamRepository
                .findByNumberAndGameType(
                        result.getRobot().getNumber(),
                        result.getScorecard().getGame().getType());
        if (existingTeam == null) {
            Team team = new Team();
            team.setNumber(result.getRobot().getNumber());
            team.setGameType(result.getMatch().getEvent().getGame().getType());
            team.setDistrict(result.getMatch().getEvent().getDistrict());
            teamRepository.save(team);
            result.getRobot().setTeam(team);
        }
    else result.getRobot().setTeam(existingTeam);
             result.getRobot().setGame(result.getMatch().getEvent().getGame());

        robotRepository.save(result.getRobot());
        entityManager.refresh(result.getRobot());
    } else result.setRobot(existingRobot);
    List<Robot> all = robotRepository.findAll();

    //replace transient FieldSections with entities from database
    //todo: reduce database hits
    //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
    result.getScores().stream()
          .peek(fieldResult -> fieldResult.setField(
                  fieldSectionRepository.findByIdAndScorecard(
                          fieldResult.getField().getId(),
                          result.getScorecard())))
              .peek(fieldResult -> {
              if (fieldResult.getField() == null)
                  throw new ScoresDoNotExistException();
          })
          .forEach(fieldResult->fieldResult.setResult(result));


    if (!result.scoresMatchScorecardSections()) {
        throw new ScoresDoNotMatchScorecardException();
    }

    if (!result.allMissingScoresAreOptional()) {
        throw new RequiredScoresAbsentException();
    }

    if (!result.gameMatchesScorecard()) {
        throw new GameDoesNotMatchScorecardException();
    }

    resultRepository.save(result);
    match.getRobots().add(result.getRobot());
    result.getRobot().getMatches().add(match);
    robotRepository.save(result.getRobot());
    matchRepository.save(match);
    entityManager.refresh(result);
    entityManager.refresh(result.getRobot());
    entityManager.refresh(match);
    return new ResultResourceAssembler().toResource(result);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code before you call `resultRepository.save(result);` in order to get an idea who your object  net looks like when you start persisting it? Better the whole method? Is this method or containing class annotated with `@Transactional`?

Comment: @ansgar-schulte I had left out the preceding part of the method because, with the exception of creating and saving the `Robot` object and giving a 404 if the `match` object is null, it has no dealings with `Robot` or `Match`. I'll go ahead and add it though.

Comment: *when I step through the c method in my debugger, I see that after the last two em.refresh lines, both e1 and e2 have their sets cleared.*: well, of course they are, since you refreshed them without flushing the changes you just made. Why do you refresh? And why do you re-save managed entities? All those re-saves and refreshes are useless, or even counter-productive. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object): *Refresh ... overwriting changes made to the entity, if any.*.

Comment: @jb-nizet I thought the save method on the JpaRepository flushed changes since it appeared to in all other circumstances. I'm refreshing so that I can see in the debugger if the changes were persisted by the save() method. replacing save with saveAndFlush leads to a "Unique index or primary key violation" on the join table (e1_e2).

Comment: @jb-nizet the re-saves and refreshes are for me viewing it in the debugger. I did not add them until after I was experiencing this issue.

Comment: @jb-nizet the exception I mentiones was from using the second definition of E2 described. with the first one, it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JpaRepository.save()` does not flush the changes to the database. It is necessary to flush the changes with `JpaRepository.flush()` or `JpaRepository.saveAndFlush()`.